# Having issues exporting FBX Character mesh and rigg into UT4

Tags: export

I'm working on a project and we're making custom models to use in UT4, however when ever we export we're getting an issue with the bones. Saying there is more then one root or it will import with nothing there.   I've followed a few other tutorials and I'm not sure where we're going wrong with this.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're not already using it, switch to Blender 2.7.2 RC; The fbx exporter has been improved.

Comment: Thanks,  Getting results now. just a few tweeks and I think we'll be up and running

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest release candidate, as of now(2.7.2 RC), and it should work much more smoothly. There were some problems with the fbx exporter which have been fixed, such as bones, vertex groups and shape keys, I think.